# How can I provide a tab completion list, with the values generated on powershell startup?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

So I have a cmdlet written in c#: `Get-LivingCharacter`. I want users to use this like `Get-LivingCharacter -Name "Bran"`, but I would like to allow for the list of available characters to change.  Maybe today, "Bran" is a valid name to pass in for `Get-LivingCharacter`, but maybe in the future it will not be. Things happen.

For convenience I want to allow tab-completion of this field. However, I can't seem to get that to work for non-const data sets. Dynamic fields don't even auto-complete the field name, nevermind the value, and I don't know a way to implement this for a non-dynamic field. Conceptually, I could generate a .ps1 file on startup given the current data set, and then load that ps1 as the module, but this feels a bit like killing a pup with a greatsword - lots of overkill. Is there a better option?

Comment: Take a look at this article (Dynamic ValidateSet in a Dynamic Parameter): http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/06/10/dynamic-validateset-in-a-dynamic-parameter.aspx

Comment: Have you considered using an Enum?  You can create a custom enum from a list outside of the function, then cast the parameter as that enum type within the function and you'll get tab completion, and can manipulate the list outside of the function.

Comment: How do you determine what the Living Character set is? Where is that data stored?

Comment: I knew I had seen something like this question before. Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993799/populate-parameter-list-from-xml/22997313) for a great write-up by Cookie Monster (with big props to mjolinor for the enum advise there too). The OP there may have accepted my answer, but even I up-voted Cookie's effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already implemented a similar function to the [DynamicParam helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993799/populate-parameter-list-from-xml/22997313), as reference in the comments.  However, tab completion wasn't working.  I was writing a minimal reproduction example, when...my tab completion worked.

It turns out, it reproducibly works/breaks based on the inclusion of a WriteDebug statement:

```
[Cmdlet("Get", "LivingCharacter")]
public class GetLivingCharacter : Cmdlet, IDynamicParameters
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
    }

    public object GetDynamicParameters()
    {
        WriteDebug("Getting names"); // Tab completion won't work with this here - comment it out and it works.
        ^^^^^^^^^^

        var chars = new List<String>() { "Bran", "Arya" };            
        var dict = new RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary();

        var attributes = new Collection<Attribute>
        {
            new ParameterAttribute
            {
                HelpMessage = "Enter a valid open name",
                Mandatory = true
            },
            new ValidateSetAttribute(chars.ToArray()),
        };

        dict.Add("Name", new RuntimeDefinedParameter("Name", typeof(string), attributes));

        return dict;
    }
}
```

After some digging, the `WriteDebug` statement is throwing (which I assume is because it can't output while I'm typing). It then recreates the GetLivingCharacter class after I've finished the command to validate. It took a while to find since, because of the issue, I can't write the error to the console, so I had to append to a temp file instead.